# How to remove dangerous permissions at runtime?

Tags: android, android-permissions

[Google Play security policy](https://play.google.com/about/privacy-security-deception/permissions/) requires that:

> Apps must be actively registered as the default SMS handler before prompting users to accept any of READ_SMS, WRITE_SMS, SEND_SMS, RECEIVE_SMS permissions and **must immediately stop the use of the permission when it's no longer the default handler.**

I know how to register as default SMS handler and request the permissions at runtime, but how do I remove those permissions myself when my app is no longer the default SMS handler?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You cannot remove permissions yourself, or even really ask the user to remove permissions.

My interpretation of that requirement is that you stop using APIs that are tied to those permissions.